# Is it possible to use a tapered fiber to collimate a single-mode light beam?

Tags: geometric-optics, fiber-optics, light-emitting-diodes

I would like to collimate a light beam stemming from a single-mode LED source. As the source is pretty big (a few millimeters), collimation with a single lens gives a bad result, *i.e.* a quite nonparallel beam.

I was wondering if a fiber optic taper could be used to create a smaller secondary source, for instance with the following setup:

[image]

My questions are:

- Would that work ?
- If yes, what are the limitations ? For instance with taping ratio, or the transmission rate.

If you are aware of some other way to reduce the size of a single-mode light source, I'd be happy to hear your suggestions.

Comment: Some standard things done with [tapered fibers](https://www.rp-photonics.com/tapered_fibers.html), but not an answer to your question.  When attempting clean-up an optical source, one loses power.  The question is always how clean do you need? and how much power do you lose?

Comment: As @PeterDiehr points out,    you can't do it without losing power.   A more common trick is to use a lens to focus the source, and then put a pinhole in the focal plane.  Obviously, you throw away a lot of light.

Comment: Take a look at Etendue: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue. In general the answer to your question will be negative. Why use an LED, anyway? Lasers are very cheap, these days, and they do exactly what you want.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I need to use a given wavelength (488nm) as the final aim is to illuminate a fluorescent protein with a sharp absorption spectrum. And at this wavelength, I can't find any laser diode at less than 2k$. Then, you are right that lasers are directly collimated, but I want to send the beam on an array of  micro-mirors so I need a rather large beam (approx 25mm or 1"). I could try to enlarge a laser beam but I expect a speckle, which I would like to avoid to ensure the homogeneity of the illumination.

Comment: Were you to use a laser, you'd still have to focus it onto a pinhole to clean up the spatial frequencies (to remove speckle).     Have you considered scanning your (reduced size) collimated beam over the mirror array?    But in any case,  I can't quite see why you need a collimated beam if all you're doing is illuminating biologics.  Can you provide more info about your experiment?

Comment: @Peter Dierh: Thanks for your comment. I saw the link before posting, and I was just wondering why tapers are not used in this way. As they already exist, it's not just a technical matter of fabrication. I knew about the pinhole technique, and I would like to compare it with the taper. Would the taper setup loose more, less or the same amount of light than a pinhole, for the same precision on the output parallelism ? Maybe my problem is that I don't really understand yet where the light is lost in the taper system.

Comment: @Carl: Thanks for your comment. Sure: I would like to set-up an optogenetic illumination system for brain tissue excitation. The idea is to illuminate a pattern in the focal plane of an objective. As I would like to reduce the out-of-focus excitation as much as possible, I would like to have a perfectly parallel beam as an input. I know this is a rather standard technique in the field to collimate a LED source, but I would like to see if we can improve the technique.

Comment: @Ratbert: Given your optical parameters I don't understand your problem to begin with. The area of an LED is small compared to the area you want to illuminate, so this will not cause a lot of loss of light. As for speckles... there are ways of dealing with those that wouldn't impact your experiment. I am getting the impression that you are looking at esoteric solutions because you lack experience with the design of conventional optics. The requirement for a "perfectly parallel beam", for instance, is completely irrelevant for your application. You probably mean "sharp outline"?